# When "draw" is called by UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a done button with a `IBAction` as following:

```
@IBAction func done() {
    print("Done pressed");
    let hudView = HudView.hud(inView: (navigationController?.view)!, animated: true)
    print("Set text");
    hudView.text = "Toggled"
}
```

The `HudView` is a subclass of `UIView` has a convinience constructor

```
class func hud(inView view: UIView, animated: Bool) -> HudView
{
    print("Constructor is called")
    let hudView = HudView(frame: view.bounds)
    hudView.isOpaque = false
    view.addSubview(hudView)
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return hudView
}
```

And also I overwrite the draw method in it.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    print("Draw is called")
    ...
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand why it prints out in such sequence

```
Done pressed
Constructor is called
Set text
Draw is called
```

Why is the draw method not called until I set the text? Why not immediately after it is constructed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple's Official [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw).

> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event
>   occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should never
>   call this method directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view,
>   and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the setNeedsDisplay()
>   or setNeedsDisplay(_:) method instead.

When you initialise the view, it's not added to the view hierarchy and display for that view is not needed. So draw(_:) is not called. When you added the view as subview to the view hierarchy, it has to display and the method is called.

Somethings other than `setNeedsDisplay()` and `setNeedsDisplay(_:)` that trigger this method are when you make layouts to the view or change the size of the view.

Comment: But after I add it as a subview(), the "Set text" is printed out firstly rather than "Draw is called", why?

Comment: @WanhuiQiao I think it's because of UIKit does not instantly draw things as you do. The framework update the screen with a timer may be 60 fps. When you load, change things and invalidate graphics, the view is marked as something like "It's view contents are invalid anymore". So UIKit will call the draw method on the next frame. Before next frame, you codes are issued on the main thread and has to wait until these are finished.